# Video Texture Shows Pink/Missing When I Share the File

Tags: rendering, image, video

I have added videos on these planes. But after sharing the file, the videos show missing and are pink, though I've packed all the ressources.
All textures worked but only the videos on the planes show missing and are pink. How to solve that?

I have zipped the file with videos, too. But when they unzip the file and open the blend file the video is still missing and pink.

I have changed the video format to see if that works... well, it didn't.

When I upload it to a cloud rendering service, the video shows missing. When I share it with someone else, the video shows missing.

[image]

Please help

Comment: Video files cannot be packed into a blend file. If the video is in a zip file with the blend but still does not show up, the video's file path may not be relative to the blend's file path.